# Breaking horizontal layout of inline-blocks in CSS

Tags: css

I have many LI that I am laying horizontaly using inline-block.

It works very nice, and I see

```
| [LI1]-[LI2]-[LI3] |
| [LI4   ]-[LI5]    |
| [LI6]-[LI7]-[LI8] |
```

on my browser, depending on the window width and the width of the individual LI's.

I would like that after some LIs, the "line breaks". For example, putting a "linebreak" after LI2, I would see

```
| [LI1]-[LI2]       |
| [LI3]-[LI4   ]    |
| [LI5]-[LI6]-[LI7] |
| [LI8]             |
```

Of course, it could be that LI3 breaks the line too.

I have full control over the CSS for every LI.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this with a CSS trick - I'd modify my HTML to reflect the structure of the list you want to display.

Here you could say that each horizontal set of `<li>` is its own `<ul>`. So you have a list of lists.

Check [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ustVW/). 
This way you get your result without the behaviour being hidden in some CSS, and it's easy to see what's happening in your markup.

EDIT: Ok since you can't touch the HTML, you can float all your `<li>` to the left, then make the first `<li>` on each row `clear:left`. See [this edit to the JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ustVW/1/)...

Comment: Hi! The problem is that I am not able to modify the HTML. just the CSS :-(

Comment: You are my hero! I can't vote for you... reputation < 15. I'm really sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific element to "line break" you just need to add a clear.

```
.myelement {
  clear: both;
}


<li>Hi</li>
<li>There</li>
<li class="myelement">Neighbor!</li>
```

Elements naturally migrate to the left.  If all the elements are set to float: left, they will all migrate to the left and then break each time they run out of room.  `clear:both;` makes them be the only item on that line.